# MVC loop in database table

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller

I have a form with some textboxfors.

one of the textbox is for a barcode.
Now when i give in that field a barcode and i click on make a order.

Then i want loop in the database for comparing the barcode with the correct article.

I have try with a foreach loop for loop and while loop but get Always a nullreferenceexception.

How can i loop in the database table for compare a textboxfor field with the database field ?

view

```
@model ReservatieMVC.ViewModels.AddtocartSubmit
@using EindwerkDatabase.lib.Models



<style>
    #qtyTextbox {
        width: 50px;
        height: 35px;
        bottom: 10px;
    }

    .submitCart {
        float: right;
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
</style>

<div id="quantity">




    @Html.Hidden("artikelId", ViewData["artikel"])


</div>

<div>@ViewBag.ArtikelId</div>
@{Html.BeginForm("Addtocart", "Artikels");}

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {


        .test = @Model.artikelId;
    })
</script>

<div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.artikelId, new { @class = "logger" })



    <b>Barcode Student @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentBarCode)</b>
    <b>Start UileenDatum: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.startdatum, new { id = "datepicker" }) @*<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width:150px"*@ </b>
    <br /> <br />
    <b>Teruggave:  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.einddatum, new { id = "datepicker2" }) @*<input type="text" id="datepicker2" style="width:150px"*@  </b>

</div>

<input class="submitCart" type="submit" value="Voeg toe">

@{Html.EndForm();}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addtocart(AddtocartSubmit model,Reservatie res)
{
    Reservatie re = new Reservatie();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         while(model.StudentBarCode == res.Gebruiker.StudentBarCode)
         {
             break;
         }

         re.ArtikelId = model.artikelId;
         //re.ArtikelId = model.artikelId;
         string datumstart = model.startdatum;
         string datumeind = model.einddatum;
         re.startdatum = Convert.ToDateTime(datumstart);
         re.einddatum = Convert.ToDateTime(datumeind);

         re.GebruikerId = 3;

         re.Datum = DateTime.Today;
         r.Reservatie.Add(re);
         r.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: what is the actual exception you are getting and the stack trace?

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code i get on my while loop

Comment: It could be that 'res.Gebruiker' is null. Or even res, where is this coming from?

Comment: I'm guessing either datumstart or einddatum is null in the database for one of the records.

Comment: res = reservatie and is comming out the database, AddtocartSubmit is a viewmodel from the values of my textboxfor. Ye but how can i made a loop into the database and break when the value of my viewmodel == the value of my database table row ?

Comment: i want only when i scan the barcode that he shows the productname.